# Ruby on Rails: Date Picker not saving format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, format

I have a form that creates a new entry into a database. One of the fields uses jquery Datepicker. At the moment, I can pick a date using the UI calendar and it displays in the right format in the textbox, but when I submit the form, the format changes back to the default setting, and saves in the database. I have had this working before on a older version of my site, and I tried following questions already posted, but had no luck. Hopefully someone can see the problem. Thanks.

Here's part of my Project Controller:

```
def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])


    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @project.exception_pm = params[:new_exception_pm] unless params[:new_exception_pm].blank?
    @project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
    @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
    @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's part of my form view:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>


  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, :class => 'datepicker' %>
  </div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :end_date, :class => 'datepicker' %>
  </div>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my application.js file:

```
$(function() {
  $("#project_start_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});

$(function() {
  $("#project_end_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you are calling datepicker() 3 times for each of the controls?  Try narrowing that down to once and fiddling with the parameters, you probably are getting conflicts between them.

Comment: I have edited my code, I need to use datepicker twice for the start date and end date. I have removed the main.js.coffee file

Comment: what about the script tag at the bottom of the layout/application view?

Comment: yeah sorry, removed that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with the saving of the date, but with the display of the date. Dates are stored in the database as dates, not strings, so when you view the date, it is shown as the default output format after rails converts the type.

In your view, you need to format it with `strftime` or possibly use [I18N routines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Just changed the database to accept the date as a string. :)

Comment: So your saying keep the format as date in the database, but change the way it's presented?

Comment: exactly.  There are several way to do this check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using strftime you can quickly set a universal default format for your date by creating date_formats.rb in the config/initializers and adding this line:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m-%d-%Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery by default gives me mm/dd/yyyy. So in my controller, I parse the params using

```
to_date = DateTime.strptime(params["to_date"],'%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
from_date = DateTime.strptime(params["from_date"], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This works in formatting well.  All date formatting API's are available at [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html).